# Cache store [] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run laravel application.
I have an error:

```
In CacheManager.php line 98:

  Cache store [] is not defined.


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

when I run:

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
```

My cache.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default cache connection that gets used while
    | using this caching library. This connection is used when another is
    | not explicitly specified when executing a given caching function.
    |
    | Supported: "apc", "array", "database", "file",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Stores
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the cache "stores" for your application as
    | well as their drivers. You may even define multiple stores for the
    | same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.
    |
    */

    'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'cache',
        ],

        'dynamodb' => [
            'driver' => 'dynamodb',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
            'table' => env('DYNAMODB_CACHE_TABLE', 'cache'),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Key Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing a RAM based store such as APC or Memcached, there might
    | be other applications utilizing the same cache. So, we'll specify a
    | value to get prefixed to all our keys so we can avoid collisions.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_cache'),

];
```

`php artisan --version` gives me the same error:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

In CacheManager.php line 98:

  Cache store [] is not defined.
```

I guess I am missing some dependency but not sure how to fix it.

## Update

In .env file I have:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

And here my vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Cache;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory as FactoryContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;

/**
 * @mixin \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository
 */
class CacheManager implements FactoryContract
{
    /**
     * The application instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * The array of resolved cache stores.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $stores = [];

    /**
     * The registered custom driver creators.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $customCreators = [];

    /**
     * Create a new Cache manager instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application  $app
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    /**
     * Get a cache store instance by name, wrapped in a repository.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository
     */
    public function store($name = null)
    {
        $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();

        return $this->stores[$name] = $this->get($name);
    }

    /**
     * Get a cache driver instance.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $driver
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository
     */
    public function driver($driver = null)
    {
        return $this->store($driver);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to get the store from the local cache.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository
     */
    protected function get($name)
    {
        return $this->stores[$name] ?? $this->resolve($name);
    }

    /**
     * Resolve the given store.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    protected function resolve($name)
    {
        $config = $this->getConfig($name);

        if (is_null($config)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cache store [{$name}] is not defined.");
        }

        if (isset($this->customCreators[$config['driver']])) {
            return $this->callCustomCreator($config);
        } else {
            $driverMethod = 'create'.ucfirst($config['driver']).'Driver';

            if (method_exists($this, $driverMethod)) {
                return $this->{$driverMethod}($config);
            } else {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("Driver [{$config['driver']}] is not supported.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call a custom driver creator.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function callCustomCreator(array $config)
    {
        return $this->customCreators[$config['driver']]($this->app, $config);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of the APC cache driver.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Cache\Repository
     */
    protected function createApcDriver(array $config)
    {
        $prefix = $this->getPrefix($config);

        return $this->repository(new ApcStore(new ApcWrapper, $prefix));
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of the array cache driver.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Cache\Repository
     */
    protected function createArrayDriver()
    {
        return $this->repository(new ArrayStore);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of the file cache driver.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Cache\Repository
     */
    protected function createFileDriver(array $config)
    {
        return $this->repository(new FileStore($this->app['files'], $config['path']));
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of the Memcached cache driver.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Cache\Repository
     */
    protected function createMemcachedDriver(array $config)
    {
        $prefix = $this->getPrefix($config);

        $memcached = $this->app['memcached.connector']->connect(
            $config['servers'],
            $config['persistent_id'] ?? null,
            $config['options'] ?? [],
            array_filter($config['sasl'] ?? [])
        );

        return $this->repository(new MemcachedStore($memcached, $prefix));
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of the Null cache driver.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Cache\Repository
     */
    protected function createNullDriver()
    {
        return $this->repository(new NullStore);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of the Redis cache driver.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Cache\Repository
     */
    protected function createRedisDriver(array $config)
    {
        $redis = $this->app['redis'];

        $connection = $config['connection'] ?? 'default';

        return $this->repository(new RedisStore($redis, $this->getPrefix($config), $connection));
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of the database cache driver.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Cache\Repository
     */
    protected function createDatabaseDriver(array $config)
    {
        $connection = $this->app['db']->connection($config['connection'] ?? null);

        return $this->repository(
            new DatabaseStore(
                $connection, $config['table'], $this->getPrefix($config)
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of the DynamoDB cache driver.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Cache\Repository
     */
    protected function createDynamodbDriver(array $config)
    {
        $dynamoConfig = [
            'region' => $config['region'],
            'version' => 'latest',
            'endpoint' => $config['endpoint'] ?? null,
        ];

        if ($config['key'] && $config['secret']) {
            $dynamoConfig['credentials'] = Arr::only(
                $config, ['key', 'secret', 'token']
            );
        }

        return $this->repository(
            new DynamoDbStore(
                new DynamoDbClient($dynamoConfig),
                $config['table'],
                $config['attributes']['key'] ?? 'key',
                $config['attributes']['value'] ?? 'value',
                $config['attributes']['expiration'] ?? 'expires_at',
                $this->getPrefix($config)
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create a new cache repository with the given implementation.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store  $store
     * @return \Illuminate\Cache\Repository
     */
    public function repository(Store $store)
    {
        $repository = new Repository($store);

        if ($this->app->bound(DispatcherContract::class)) {
            $repository->setEventDispatcher(
                $this->app[DispatcherContract::class]
            );
        }

        return $repository;
    }

    /**
     * Get the cache prefix.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPrefix(array $config)
    {
        return $config['prefix'] ?? $this->app['config']['cache.prefix'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the cache connection configuration.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getConfig($name)
    {
        return $this->app['config']["cache.stores.{$name}"];
    }

    /**
     * Get the default cache driver name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDefaultDriver()
    {
        return $this->app['config']['cache.default'];
    }

    /**
     * Set the default cache driver name.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDefaultDriver($name)
    {
        $this->app['config']['cache.default'] = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Unset the given driver instances.
     *
     * @param  array|string|null  $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function forgetDriver($name = null)
    {
        $name = $name ?? $this->getDefaultDriver();

        foreach ((array) $name as $cacheName) {
            if (isset($this->stores[$cacheName])) {
                unset($this->stores[$cacheName]);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Register a custom driver creator Closure.
     *
     * @param  string  $driver
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return $this
     */
    public function extend($driver, Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->customCreators[$driver] = $callback->bindTo($this, $this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Dynamically call the default driver instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        return $this->store()->$method(...$parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put `CacheManager.php` code ?

Comment: Which cache store are you trying to use? (`CACHE_DRIVER` in ,`.env` file)

Comment: Check your .env, I guess `CACHE_DRIVER` is empty

Comment: posted  CacheManager.php in the update above, CACHE_DRIVER=file in .env

Comment: The error is because some service is trying to use a `""` store, i tried to replicate the error in my local machine and i get the exact same error when i don't put any value in `CACHE_DRIVER`, you should try to remove all extra packages in your `composer.json` until it works (maybe you forgot to publish a conf file from a package)

Comment: ps: if you try `php artisan -vvv` you can go check in your log file (default at `storage/logs/laravel.log`) you can see the full stracktrace of the error and maybe it can help you

Comment: @GummaMocciaro you are right, I had to do `set -a; . .env; set +a` to fix empty environment CACHE_DRIVER value in my docker stack container. Although, it was set CACHE_DRIVER=file in .env file before. Not sure why just putting CACHE_DRIVER value in .env wasn't enough. But anyway, fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

update 'cache_driver' on your env like following -

`CACHE_DRIVER=file`

Answer (score -6):

## Right Answer

**First**: change the name of config.php in bootsrap/cache to any name to stop file for example rename to config.php_old 
**Second**: php artisan config:clear
**Third**: php aritsan config:cache

and then laravel automaticly make config.php file and the problem solve 
I hope help you **(Gaza/Palestine)**
**#*mohammad sultan***

Comment: Please don't add right answer, you don't know if this answer can help or not.